# Where should I put my package files in TeX Live 2013?

Tags: packages, texlive, texmaker

I am using texmaker, which is based on Tex Live 2013. I have just downloaded a package, i.e. mathpro2 (lite version).

Question 1: Where should I put my package files into?

I have seen answers to this question, but I am still entirely not sure where exactly should I put my `mtp2lite` folder. Right now, I have the following file path

```
`\usr\local\texlive\`
```

Inside `texlive`, there are 2 folders `2013` and `texmf-local`.

`2013` contains `texmf-config`, `texmf-dist` and `texmf-var`.

Inside `texmf-local`, there are 6 other folders; `bibtex`, `dvips`, `fonts`, `metapost`, `tex`, and `web2c`.

But I am not sure where to place my "`mtp2lite`" folder in?

Question 2: My `mtp2lite` folder 2 folders, `template` and `texmf`. And the `texmf` contains several other folders `doc`, `dvips`, `fonts`, `source`, `tex`, and `tpm` but I was expecting **files** with `.sty` extension. Not sure where they are? Am I suppose to extract something from these folders? Put simply, what should I do such that when I compile my TeX files in Texmaker with the following command, everything will work smoothly?

```
\usepackage[lite]{mtpro2}
```

I am just really confused here.

**UPDATE:** Someone said that it suffices to unzip the `mtp2lite.zip` file. However, I am not sure which file path should I unzip the file ?

1. `\usr\local\texlive\2013\texmf-config`
2. `\usr\local\texlive\2013\texmf-dist`
3. `\usr\local\texlive\texmf-local`

I unzip the files in all 3 paths, and in the terminal I ran the following command:

`sudo mktexlsr /usr/local/texlive/2013/`

and

`sudo updmap-sys --enable Map=mtpro2.map`

The terminal output gave me this after the second command:

`updmap is using the following updmap.cfg files (in precedence order):
  /usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-config/web2c/updmap.cfg
  /usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/web2c/updmap.cfg
updmap is using the following updmap.cfg file for writing changes:
  /usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-config/web2c/updmap.cfg
/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-config/web2c/updmap.cfg unchanged.  Map files not recreated.`

I am Not sure if this is actually a problem.

But when I tried to compile my tex file, I am still getting error message:

```
 I can't find file `mt2exa'. <*> ...:=ljfour; mag:=1; nonstopmode; input mt2exa Please type another input file name ! Emergency stop. <*> ...:=ljfour; mag:=1; nonstopmode; input mt2exa Transcript written on mfput.log.

grep: mt2exa.log: No such file or directory
```

Comment: You will have to merge the two folders: The content of the dvips folder must go in the dvips folder of texmf-local etc. Check the temxf-dist folder to understand the structure of a texmf tree. After you did put everything in the correct folder you should enable the map file (in the dvips folder) with updmap-sys.

Comment: So, the content of `doc,dvips,fonts,source,tex,tpm` from the mtp2lite must go in the corresponding folders of textmf-local ?

Comment: @asd - Yes, that's the best route. Note that it's not necessary to call the various subdirectories `mtpro2lite`; using the name `mtpro2` will do just fine.

Comment: Wait, I am not sure if I am getting this. My `mtp2lite` folder actually has 2 folders, `templates` and `texmf`. And the `texmf` contains `doc,dvips,fonts,source,tex,tpm`. But in my `texmf-local` folder, it doesn't contain folders like `doc,source,tpm` and the `template` folder ? And also, do I need to change the names of the subdirectories ? I am confused. Sorry

Comment: You just have to copy (or unzip) the content of `texmf\` at the root of your `texmf-local\` directory. This will automatically create the required directories and everything will be in its right place. Don't forget to  run `updmap-sys`, as Ulrike Fischer said.

Comment: What is `updamp-sys` ? And where should I run it ? Sorry, I am a complete noob on these things

Comment: `updmap-sys` updates the information TeX has about fonts. After you place the files by unzipping as explained above, you need to do two things. First, `mktexlsr /usr/local/texlive/texmf-local`. This will update the filename database for that tree. Then run `updmap-sys --enable Map=mapname.map` where `mapname.map` is the name of the map file installed under `dvips`. Do this in the Terminal application (probably in `/Applications/Utilities/`) using `sudo`. That is, you actually write `sudo mktexlsr...` `sudo updmap-sys...` etc. You will be asked for your password.

Comment: I unzip the contents in 3 different paths, as I am not sure which one to go for.
1. `/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local`
2. `/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-config`
3. `/usr/local/texlive/texmf-dist`
I also ran the commands in terminal but i am still getting errors. Please see update in question

Answer (score 3):

I moved manually the contents of the .zip file, but it should be equivalent to unzip in

```
/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local
```

Here's the structure I have (the first line is how I output it):

```
> locate mtpro2 | grep texmf-local | grep 'mtpro2$'
/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local/doc/fonts/mtpro2
/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local/dvips/mtpro2
/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local/fonts/map/dvips/mtpro2
/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local/fonts/tfm/pctex/mtpro2
/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local/fonts/type1/pctex/mtpro2
/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local/source/latex/mtpro2
/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local/tex/latex/mtpro2
/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local/tex/plain/mtpro2
```

This should reflect the structure of the ZIP file (apart perhaps from the subtree I created for `pctex` metric files and Type1 fonts).

After unzipping the file (and moving the files manually, in my case), I simply added a line to the file

```
/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local/web2c/updmap.cfg
```

so that it contains the line

```
Map mtpro2.map
```

(I have other similar instructions for other locally installed fonts). The file must be created, if still not existent. The final operations are the following command lines

```
mktexlsr
updmap-sys
```

that must be performed with suitable privileges just like the unzipping/moving procedure (for Mac OS X it is using the `sudo` prefix).

Adding the line to the “local” `updmap.cfg` file guarantees that the map file will always be taken into account in next runs of `updmap-sys` and will survive updates of TeX Live when the next release is installed.